# Prove constant times invertible matrix is also invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\beta \neq 0$.
Show $\beta B \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

What I tried: I know it intuitively makes sense that this would be the case, but I can't see how to prove this other than factoring out the constant from the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero.

By properties of determinants, $\det(\beta B) = \beta^n \det(B)$ which is nonzero since $\beta\neq 0$ and $\det(B)\neq 0$

Comment: This proof is useful if the OP has already covered determinants. If they're still in the preliminary chapters of matrix algebra, then the determinant is likely to not have been covered yet.

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is invertible, then $B^{-1}$ exists. If $\beta \neq 0$, then $\frac1\beta$ exists. Now do the calculation
$$
(\beta B)\cdot\left(\frac1\beta B^{-1}\right)
$$